# drawRect function of Qpainter not giving rectangles of equal dimension

Tags: qt

In Qt i have a Qpixmap of 5 px width and 4 px height ,I am filling it with rectangles of width .08 and height .08 but the rectangles formed are not of equal dimension as I have given`.
I want to draw alternate black and white rectangles of equal dimension

```
QLabel *a=new QLabel();
QPixmap b(5,4);
a->setFixedSize(b.size());
QPainter painter(&b);
heightOfCheckeredBox=.08;
widthOfCheckeredBox=.08;
bool switchBetweenBlackAndWhiteBoxRowDirection=true;
int  switchBetweenBlackAndWhiteBoxColumnDirection=0;
for(qreal i=0;i<4;i+=heightOfCheckeredBox)
{
    for(qreal j=0;j<5;j+=widthOfCheckeredBox)
    {
        if(switchBetweenBlackAndWhiteBoxRowDirection)
        {



            painter.setPen(Qt::white);
            painter.setBrush(Qt::white);

            switchBetweenBlackAndWhiteBoxRowDirection=false;

        }
        else
        {

            painter.setPen(Qt::gray);
            painter.setBrush(Qt::gray);
            switchBetweenBlackAndWhiteBoxRowDirection=true;
        }

        QRectF rectangle(j,i,widthOfCheckeredBox,heightOfCheckeredBox);
        painter.drawRect(rectangle);

    }

    switchBetweenBlackAndWhiteBoxColumnDirection++;
    if(int(switchBetweenBlackAndWhiteBoxColumnDirection)%2==0)
        switchBetweenBlackAndWhiteBoxRowDirection=true;
    else
        switchBetweenBlackAndWhiteBoxRowDirection=false;
}

a->setPixmap(b);
a->show();
```

Comment: Ask yourself what it means to draw a rectangle whose width and height are 8 hundredths of a pixel.  What do you expect the underlying rendering algorithms to do?

Comment: Draw it at a scale where you can use whole (or nearly whole) pixels, then scale it down with a known algorithm.

Comment: I have a image i need to have a another image in background of it which is my checkered image that i am making with white and black boxes now for different images i need checkered boxes of equal dimension in every case after that it is done fit in view

Answer (score 0):

Since you're drawing without antialiasing, the tiny pixel size makes little sense - what did you expect?

The size of the pixmap is given in pixels. Your pixmap contains 5x4 = 20 pixels. You're trying to draw 20 rectangles on it. For this to work, each rectangle must be a square exactly one pixel wide and high. Alas, you're trying to draw squares 12.5x smaller than a pixel. That doesn't make much sense, and I have no idea where you got the value of 0.08 from. Just draw the squares one pixel wide.

Example:

```
// https://github.com/KubaO/stackoverflown/tree/master/questions/checkered-paint-42205180
#include <QtWidgets>

QPixmap checkers(const QSizeF & rectSize, const QSize & pixmapSize) {
   QPixmap pixmap{pixmapSize};
   QPainter painter{&pixmap};
   painter.setPen(Qt::NoPen);
   const QColor colors[] = {Qt::white, Qt::black};
   QPointF pos{};
   bool oddRow{}, color{};
   while (pos.y() < pixmap.height()) {
      painter.setBrush(colors[color ? 1 : 0]);
      painter.drawRect({pos, rectSize});
      color = !color;
      pos.setX(pos.x() + rectSize.width());
      if (pos.x() >= pixmap.width()) {
         pos.setX({});
         pos.setY(pos.y() + rectSize.height());
         oddRow = !oddRow;
         color = oddRow;
      }
   }
   return pixmap;
}

int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
   QApplication app{argc, argv};
   QLabel label;
   auto pix = checkers({1, 1}, {60, 30});
   label.resize(200, 200);
   label.setAlignment(Qt::AlignCenter);
   label.setPixmap(pix);
   label.show();
   return app.exec();
}
```